# How to connect components of VHDL code

Tags: counter, vhdl

I have 2 components that have worked separately in simulation, but now I'm confused on how to implement the design onto my board. I have one design that is a binary to 7-segment display, and another that is a counter that counts upwards in seconds.

How do I connect these two to work together to show values onto a basys2 board?

Code for timer

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
ENTITY clock IS
port(reset,clk,start,stop:in std_logic;
min,sec:out integer);
end clock;
architecture behaviour of clock is
begin
process(reset,clk,start,stop)
variable tempmin,tempsec:integer:=0;
begin
if(reset='1')then
tempmin:=0;
tempsec:=0;
elsif(stop='1')then
min<=tempmin;
sec<=tempsec;
elsif(start='1')then
if(rising_edge(clk))then
tempsec:=tempsec+1;
if(tempsec=60)then
tempsec:=0;
tempmin:=tempmin+1;
if(tempmin=10)then
tempmin:=0;
end if;
end if;
end if;
end if;
min<=tempmin;
sec<=tempsec;
end process;
end behaviour;
```

Code for binary to 7-segment

```
architecture Behavioral of SevenSegment is
begin 
process (seg_value)
begin  
if (seg_value = "0000") then
seg <= "0000001";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "0001") then
seg <= "1001111";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "0010") then
seg <= "0010010";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "0011") then
seg <= "0000110";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "0100") then
seg <= "1001100";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "0101") then
seg <= "0100100";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "0110") then
seg <= "0100000";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "0111") then
seg <= "0001111";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "1000") then
seg <= "0000000";
an <= "1100";
elsif (seg_value = "1001") then
seg <= "0000100";
an <= "1100";
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Create a top-level entity; instantiate the clock module in it; create an entity for your 7-segement code; instantiate it in the top module.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the syntax for component instantiation (or entity instantion) in your VHDL textbook. Emacs VHDL mode and Sigasi provide power-templates so you don't have to type so much code: http://www.sigasi.com/screencast/entity-instantiation